# Unable to import (require) 'cutorch' in Torch

Tags: lua, ubuntu-14.04, torch, luajit

I have CUDA 7.5 installed on my machine and installed Torch by following the instructions [here](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html). Before installing Torch I upgraded CMake to version 3.2.x.x. Then I installed `cutorch` and `cunn` using the following commands:

```
luarocks install cutorch
luarocks install cunn
```

While installing cutorch I saw some messages say8ing that CUDA 7.5 was found on my machine. However, I am unable to import `cutorch` using `require 'cotorch` and get the following error when I try to run it using the torch (th) interpreter in Terminal:

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-8316/cutorch/lib/THC/THCGeneral.c line=17 error=30 : unknown error
/home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384: cuda runtime error (30) : unknown error at /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-8316/cutorch/lib/THC/THCGeneral.c:17
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384: in function 'require'
    [string "_RESULT={require "cutorch"}"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:651: in function 'repl'
    ...amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:199: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

Then I followed the instructions [here](http://www.lighting-torch.com/2015/07/27/configuring-eclipse-with-torch/) to be able to use Eclipse to write Lua/Torch code. There, I get the following error when trying to execute `require 'cutorch'`:

```
qlua: /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cutorch/init.lua:2: cannot load '/home/amir/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libcutorch.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x7f05cf9709e0
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cutorch/init.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /home/amir/workspace/test/src/main.lua:2: in function 'main'
    /home/amir/workspace/test/src/main.lua:6: in main chunk
```

This is however the file `libcutorch.so` is in the mentioned directory. [This](https://github.com/torch/cutorch/issues/210) also did not help me resolve the issue. Does anyone know should I go about resolving the issue?

When I enter `luarocks list` I get the followings:

```
Installed rocks:
----------------

argcheck
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

cudnn
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

cunn
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

cunnx
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

cutorch
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

cwrap
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

dok
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

env
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

fftw3
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

gnuplot
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

graph
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

graphicsmagick
   1.scm-0 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

image
   1.1.alpha-0 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

lbase64
   20120820-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

lua-cjson
   2.1devel-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

luaffi
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

luafilesystem
   1.6.3-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

luasocket
   3.0rc1-2 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

nn
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

nngraph
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

nnx
   0.1-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

optim
   1.0.5-0 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

paths
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

penlight
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

qtlua
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

qttorch
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

signal
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

sundown
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

sys
   1.1-0 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

threads
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

torch
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

trepl
   scm-1 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks

xlua
   1.0-0 (installed) - /home/amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks
```

Comment: do `ldd /home/amir/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libcutorch.so` in the terminal and see if it is linked correctly to all if its dependencies.

Comment: @siavashk It seems that is is correctly linked to all the dependencies. When I run the command, I am getting things like `libluaT.so => /home/amir/torch/install/lib/libluaT.so (0x00007fd568c94000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's how you can resolve the problem (thanks to alban desmaison on Torch7 google group):

- Make sure you follow all the steps I mentioned in the question in order to make sure CUDA is installed correctly.
- If you have Theano installed, execute `sudo python`
- Then do `import theano`
- Then go to CUDA samples folder and `make` one of the samples (does not matter which one)
- Then do `./[name_of_the_sample]`
- Then Torch will easily be able use CUDA backend

**If you do not have** Theano installed, try running the CUDA samples using `sudo`. The **important step** is to be able to run one of the CUDA samples.

Now you're all set!

Comment: does that imply that prior to running any CUDA sample CUDA is not actually fully built?

Comment: No I think some links to CUDA libraries are missing. Although there is a way to get around this issue but I don't remember how

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo bash /torch/update.sh`